# Symfony2 SwiftMailer Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

After reading an testing a lot of solutions, I still getting this error.

My parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: symfony
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    secret: holamundo
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_encryption: ssl
    mailer_port: 465
    mailer_auth_mode: login
    mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
    mailer_user: justexample@gmail.com
    mailer_password: nottherealone
```

And my config.yml

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    encryption: %mailer_encryption%
    auth_mode: %mailer_auth_mode%
    host: %mailer_host%
    port: %mailer_port%
    username: %mailer_user%
    password: %mailer_password%
    spool: { type: memory }
```

And testing swiftmailer trough command line...

```
php bin/console swiftmailer:email:send
```

I get this error:

```
[app] Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0] [] []
```

If I ping 'smtp.gmail.com' I get a response back.

I'm running symfony on localhost:8000, many people say to change mailer_host to something like...

```
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
```

But I'm running it on a different port, so if I put this

```
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1:8000
```

or even this

```
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_port: 8000
```

I get:

```
ERROR     [app] Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message "" [] []
```

Thanks !

Comment: Sounds like your ISP may be blocking outbound SMTP. Please don't tag questions with PHPMailer if you're not using it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use gmail for testing purpose your parameter.yml file should look like this

```
mailer_transport: gmail
mailer_host: null
mailer_user: email_address
mailer_password: 'password'
```

To use it in your Controller

```
    $messenger = \Swift_Message::newInstance();
    $messenger->setFrom(array("email_address" => "The name you want to be displayed "));

   $messenger->setTo(array($email1, $email2, ...));
   $messenger->setCc(array($email1, $email2, ...));      
   $messenger->setSubject($subject);
   $messenger->setBody($body, 'text/html');      
   $this->mailer->send($messenger);
```

For more information about sending email in symfony have a look here
https://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html

Answer (score 0):

Try deactivating your antivirus. Avast was blocking my send email action and Symfony 3 gave me that same error message!!
hope it helps