# The Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com symfony 4

Tags: symfony, smtp, gmail, swiftmailer

When I try to send an e-mail in dev env with symfony 4 I have

> Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]

my .env is
MAILER_URL=gmail://xxxxxx:xxxxxx@localhost

I 've tried 
MAILER_URL=gmail://xxxxx:xxxxx@localhost?encryption=tls

But same error.

My fuction

```
    public function sendEmail( \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
{
    $message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
        ->setFrom('send@example.com')
        ->setTo('recipient@example.com')
        ->setBody(
            $this->renderView(
            // templates/emails/registration.html.twig
                'emails/registration.html.twig',
                array('name' => 'romain')
            ),
            'text/html'
        )
        /*
         * If you also want to include a plaintext version of the message
        ->addPart(
            $this->renderView(
                'emails/registration.txt.twig',
                array('name' => $name)
            ),
            'text/plain'
        )
        */
    ;

    $mailer->send($message);

    return new Response('<body>mail ok</body>');
}
```

I see that the mail is correctly generated with the debug bar, it's only the smtp of gmail who does not work.

Someone could help?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, Have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48842066/symfony2-swiftmailer-connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-smtp-gmail-co

Comment: Do you use a docker?